# Argument of type 'HTMLCanvasElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have the following code, that does not get compiled:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {Card, Image} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import * as chart from 'chart.js'



export const PieChartCard = () => {

    const cvRef = React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {

        const c = new chart.Chart(cvRef.current, {

        })
    });

    return (
        <Card>
            <canvas ref={cvRef} width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>Matthew</Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>
                    <span className='date'>Joined in 2015</span>
                </Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description>
                    Matthew is a musician living in Nashville.
                </Card.Description>
            </Card.Content>
        </Card>
    )

}
```

The compiler complains

```
Argument of type 'HTMLCanvasElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | HTMLCanvasElement | CanvasRenderingContext2D | ArrayLike<HTMLCanvasElement | CanvasRenderingContext2D>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | HTMLCanvasElement | CanvasRenderingContext2D | ArrayLike<HTMLCanvasElement | CanvasRenderingContext2D>'.  TS2345

    11 |     useEffect(() => {
    12 | 
  > 13 |         const c = new chart.Chart(cvRef.current, {
       |                                   ^
    14 | 
    15 |         })
    16 |     });
```

I am trying to use [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html) in React. How to avoid `null` initial value or what do I have to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider to observe changes of your ref until it become not null.

```
useEffect(() => {
   //Check for cvRef.current != null
}, [cvRef] );
```